# What are the differences between virtualbox-linux and installed-linux?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is using virtualbox for running linux any different than installing linux on the machine except for performance ? Are there any drawbacks from using virtual box to run linux than trying the real thing ? Are there any advantages ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199690/running-windows-programs-on-linux-via-vm-or-playonlinux/202132#202132

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you only need the convenience of a bash script, I do not know why someone should bother to install GNU/linux in a separate partition for this. If you run linux through a VM from an MS OS, you will obviously not have the same freedom accessing devices as from within a linux separate installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used virtualbox quite a lot and I love using it.

Here are some advantages that I see in the scenario that you are in:

1. You can easily clone virtualbox VMs. Once you have configured a VM to your liking, you can clone and multiply that image.
2. Because you can clone them easily you can have a playground in which to test or try new things. If you break it, no problem just delete the VM and recreate a new one.
3. There are some apps that don't play nice with other apps. For instance, some VPN apps can restrict Internet access across the system. You can run these apps in a VM and be able to easily switch in and out.
4. Having a VM, gives you the ability to access the best or favorite tools available in Linux or in various other OS. Its a good way to learn and explore Linux and other new OS releases and systems.

For me, there are few drawbacks to running Linux or any OS as a virtual box client, but here are some:

1. There is a performance overhead for virtualizing a client OS but for me, this is often negligible. Almost imperceptible in terms of the interactive experience.
2. You do have to have sufficient RAM and CPU to allocate to the client OS if you run one, so always check that you do have enough resources before starting up a VM. Otherwise, the overall host and client system performance will be poor.
3. You have to allocate enough diskspace for your VM images.
4. It can be tricky or impossible to get access to certain devices on the host, but Virtualbox does support USB passthrough, so more often than not, a USB device will work in a client VM environment.

If you install Virtualbox guest additions, that will make many tasks easier including seamless mouse and copy-paste integration. Also, virtualbox makes it easy to connect to the host internal network to share resources across.